# How to extract all PDF-Meta information in a folder with python?

Tags: python

I have a folder with pdfs inside. Is it possible to create a python code to extract all meta information of this pdf files?

I tried already some workable scripts like

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

fp = open('diveintopython.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)

print(doc.info)  # The "Info" metadata
```

But you can only extract from one pdf not the full folder of pdf at once.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
import PyPDF2

folder_path = 'path/to/folder/containing/pdfs'
output_file = 'pdf_metadata.csv'

# Create a CSV file to write the metadata
with open(output_file, 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write('Filename,Title,Author,Creator,Producer,CreationDate,ModDate\n')

    # Loop through each PDF file in the folder
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            filepath = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

            # Open the PDF file and read its metadata
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as pdf_file:
                pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
                metadata = pdf_reader.getDocumentInfo()

                # Write the metadata to the CSV file
                csv_file.write(f'{filename},{metadata.title},{metadata.author},{metadata.creator},'
                               f'{metadata.producer},{metadata.get('/CreationDate', '')},{metadata.get('/ModDate', '')}\n')
```

Comment: f'{metadata.producer},{metadata.get('CreationDate', '')},{metadata.get('/ModDate', '')}\n')
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('